# python feature scaling, short function

Tags: python

Have some trouble with writing a small function for feature scaling.

```
data = [115, 140, 175]

def featureScaling(arr):
    for a in arr:
        return (a-min(data))/float((max(data)-min(data)))
print featureScaling(data)
```

I know there is a potential corner case if all values in data are the same ( division by zero problem)

I just don't know why my idea does not work, since `min(data)` on its on works.

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in 
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_czbvlzqfxl/main.py", line 2, in 
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_czbvlzqfxl/studentMain.py", line 29, in 
    elif not compare_numbers(student_output[0], solution_output[0]):
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: How did you initialize `arr`?

Comment: The code in your question can not give this error. Please [edit] your question and include the code that is actually calling `featureScaling` and that includes the line that throws the error.

Comment: could you provide the full trace back and a even more elaborate code this code does not produce error and by retruning you are only returning the first process output

Comment: from your trace back it is clear that this part is not the problem please provide the full code and the other thing is student_output is a float you are trying to access it's first element like it is a list .Since there is no `__getitem__ ` method for float it produces this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tichodroma noted this code does not throw an error, however I do not believe it performs as you intended at any rate. It returns a single value but I believe you actually want each data point scaled, hence the following modification:

```
data = [115, 140, 175]
def featureScaling(arr):    
    scaled=[]   
    for a in arr:    
        scaled.append((a-min(data))/(max(data)-min(data)))
    return scaled
print(featureScaling(data))
```

This code provides the result `[0.0, 0.4166666666666667, 1.0]`